# Symfony Doctrine creates 1000+ Queries for a single Table

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Given an entity `Client`, I have several columns, such as clientName, clientNo, etc.
The table itself holds 250+ entries. There are several ManyToOne links, with tables that hold 500.000+ entries.

For reasons I don't understand, this query:

```php
$queryBuilder = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Client::class)
            ->createQueryBuilder('c');

$queryBuilder
    ->select('partial c.{id, buha, short, name, price1, price2, price3, price4, hasSsv, isActive}')
    ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');

$clients = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

and a twig template that only renders those fields, the profiler shows 1018 Queries in 25 Statements.

It queries for example for (which is one of the huge tables)

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\WebDatabase", mappedBy="client")
*/
protected $webDatabase;
```

but I don't know why? I tried `fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"` and `fetch="EAGER"`, both moke no difference. There are more relations like this one, which I don't care about with the above query.

I am using Symfony 4.4 with PHP 8.0 and MySQL 8 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Sounds like you use a debugger to check why this is called so many times. What does that Twig template really contain?

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that stands out to me is the `partial`, which is deprecated. I would not be surprised that you select them partially, it then gets hydrated and for a good hydrate it needs more info ans selects it.

If you can, just remove the `select` from the QB<sup>1</sup>, and/or remove the `partial`, and/or change the return to `getScalarResult`.

A simple test would be the `getScalarResult`, if you implement that, do the num of queries reduce significantly? Then its likely something with hydration.

<sup>1</sup> *Selecting what you need is a good MySQL practice, but IMO not a good Doctrine one.*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the partial keyword, you must set the HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD Flag.

```php
$clients = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->setHint(Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, true)->getResult();
```